# Exporting information to XML in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I am creating a ecommerce site using rails and I am trying to find a way to export information into a xml file. I have a table called Orders which has a has_many relationship to Line_Items. So the Order contains information such as the customers name and information and the Line_Items contains each product in their cart. What I am trying to achieve is when the admin visits the Orders.show.html.erb of an order there is a button to 'Download XML' which will export all information in the Line_Items table for the current order such as

```
<line_item>
 <product>Product Name</product>
 <quantity>1.0</quantity>
 <unit_price>2.49</unit_price>
 <total_price>2.49</unit_price>
</line_item>
```

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find a solution to just exporting the current order's line items to an xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a clause in your controller to respond_to the XML format and then link to it in your view template (as 'Download XML')

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.xml { render xml: @line_item.to_xml }
end
```

Edit: If you're looking for something more sophisticated, take a look at [Builder](http://builder.rubyforge.org/) or [Nokogiri's builder](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html)